# Hide/show stuff according to checking or unchecking a form box: Can this be done with css only?

Tags: javascript, css, hide

Can I show or hide stuff using ony css, where the stuff that hides or shows depends on checking or unchecking a form box?

Or do I need javascript for that?

Thanks for your insight!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using the "adjacent sibling" selector (`+`) and the `checked` pseudoclass.

**HTML**

```
<label>Box 1: <input type="checkbox"><span>Box 1 is checked.</span></label>
<label>Box 2: <input type="checkbox"><span>Box 2 is checked.</span></label>
<label>Box 3: <input type="checkbox"><span>Box 3 is checked.</span></label>
```

**CSS**

```
​label {display:block;}
input[type="checkbox"] + * {display:none; margin-left:1em;}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + * {display:inline;}
```

​Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LSF3C/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in certain circumstances, along these lines:

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+div{ display:none; }​
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox">hide it</input><div>show me</div>
```

See [js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jyht6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can show / hide stuff using CSS properties through JS.
Like changing 'display' property using Js.